# Max & min distance between two moving points

Tags: mathematical-optimization, geometry

I am trying to find the minimal and maximum distance between two moving points with *Mathematica* in an interval.

For example,

```
p1 = (Sin(t), Cos(t))
p2 = (Cos(3t), Sin(2t))
```

Interval is $0≤t≤2\pi$.

Can I use the command `EuclideanDistance` or should I use `FindMinimum`, `FindMaximum`, `NMinimize`, `Maximize`; and how do I use these commands in an interval?

Comment: Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried and where you are getting stuck. That way, people on this site will know exactly what help you need.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
p1 = {Sin[t], Cos[t]}; p2 = {Cos[3 t], Sin[2 t]};

tAtMin = ArgMax[{EuclideanDistance[p1, p2]^2, 0 <= t <= 2 Pi}, t]
tAtMax = ArgMin[{EuclideanDistance[p1, p2]^2, 0 <= t <= 2 Pi}, t]

ParametricPlot[{p1, p2}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02],
   Red, Thick, Dashed, Through[{Point, Line}[{p1, p2} /. t -> tAtMax]],
   Darker@Green, Thick, Dashed, Through[{Point, Line}[{p1, p2} /. t -> tAtMin]]
  }
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Here's a way to visualize the evolution of the distance as $t$ varies:

```
Animate[
 Show[{
   ParametricPlot[{p1, p2}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
    Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02],
      Red, Thick, Dashed, 
      Through[{Point, Line}[{p1, p2} /. t -> tAtMax]],
      Darker@Green, Thick, Dashed, Through[{Point, Line}[{p1, p2} /. t -> tAtMin]]
      }
    ],
   Graphics[{
     Thick, Gray, Dashed, PointSize[0.02],
     Through[{Point, Line}[{{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {Cos[3 x], Sin[2 x]}}]]
     }]
   }],
 {x, 0, 2 Pi},
 AnimationRate -> .05
]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, what an amazing answer!

Comment: @C.Woods Thank you!

Comment: Wow. Amazing, much more than I expected. Thank you very much!

Comment: @DCB I'm very glad I could help

Comment: The use of `Through[{Point, Line}[{p1, p2} /. t -> tAtMax]]` to create simultaneously the two points and the line joining them is particularly clever (sneaky?). A tip (trick?) well worth remembering!